# How can I get the devnode of a device using its file descriptor

Tags: c, linux

For example I opened up 2 devices in an array of devices..

NODES are /dev/ttyUSB0, /dev/ttyUSB1 etc..

```
#define MAXDEV 4
devlist[MAXDEV];
const char *devices[] = {"/dev/ttyUSB0","/dev/ttyUSB1");


for(loop =0; loop<sizeof(devices); loop++){

    fd= open(devices[loop]);

}
```

Now I add them to the list of fds;

```
for(i=0; i<MAXDEV; i++){

if(devlist[i] != 0){
devlist[i] = fd;
fd = -1;
}

}
```

Now I read on the devices for data.

```
    for(iter=0; iter<MAXDEV; iter++){

if(FD_ISSET(devlist[iter],&fds)){

if ((nbytes = read(devlist[iter], buf, sizeof(buf)-1)) > 0 && nbytes != 0)
                    {

                 buf[nbytes] = '\0';

                     printf("Data Received on Node ???");

                    }
                if(nbytes < 0){
                            printf("connection reset\n");
                            FD_CLR(devlist[iter], &fds);
                            close(devlist[iter]);
                            devlist[iter] = 0;

                        }
                        if(nbytes ==0){
                            printf("Device Removed on Node ???\n");


                        FD_CLR(devlist[iter], &fds);
                            close(devlist[iter]);
                            devlist[iter] = 0;

                        }
    }
}
```

Now how do I get the device node using its fd?.. Thanks.

Comment: What do you call device node? What are you trying to get exactly, do you have an example?

Comment: Are you looking for the device ID as returned by [`fstat(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat)?

Comment: Well since you will not know what device is removed so i plan to use the fd to get the device node. the device node is the the port on which the device is plugged. eg. /dev/ttyUSB0, /dev/ttyUSB1 etc and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *proper* way to do this is to do your own book-keeping. That would allow you to log the device node name exactly as supplied by the user, rather than provide an equivalent, yet confusingly different one.

For example you could use a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), to associate file descriptor numbers to `char` arrays with the device name used for the corresponding `open()` call.

A simpler, but far more fragile and definitely *not* recommended, solution might involve using a simple array of pointers to `char` with an inordinately large size, in the hopes that any file descriptor value that you may encounter can be used as an index to the appropriate string without going beyond the array bounds. This is slightly easier to code than a hash table, but it *will* cause your program to die horribly if a file descriptor value exceeds the maximum allowed index in your string array.

If your program is bound to the Linux platform anyway, you might be able to, uh, *cheat* by using the `/dev/fd` directory or the `/proc` filesystem (more specifically the `/proc/self/fd` directory to which `/dev/fd` is usually a symbolic link). Both contain symbolic links that associate file descriptor values to canonical versions of the paths that where used to open the corresponding files. For example consider the following transcript:

```
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 Nov  9 23:21 0 -> /dev/pts/10
l-wx------ 1 user user 64 Nov  9 23:21 1 -> /dev/pts/10
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 Nov  9 23:21 2 -> /dev/pts/10
lr-x------ 1 user user 64 Nov  9 23:21 3 -> /proc/16437/fd/
```

You can use the [`readlink()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/readlink) system call to retrieve the target of the link that corresponds to a file descriptor of interest.

Comment: Thanks, Gonna try this one out.

Comment: I don't think that `/proc/self/fd` contains symlinks to *canonical* paths; it just contains symlinks to the path which was passed to `open`. There is nothing canonical in it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I am reasonably certain that the path is canonicalised to some degree... for example `/dev/fd` shows up as `/proc/XXXX/fd`...

Comment: You are wrong. A given inode can have several or no paths to it. This is the semantics of Unix file systems. the `/proc/` pseudo-filesystem is just Linux's way to show kernel information to user-land processes.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I think we are arguing for no reason. Sure, there is no *single* canonical path, due to the existence of hard links, *but* the concept of a canonical path on Unix does exist; it's the absolute path of a file with all symbolic links resolved... see, for example, the `realpath(3)` manual page...

Comment: No, `realpath` is giving the canonical form of some given *path*, not of some given file descriptor (or inode). A file descriptor (or an inode) does not have a canonical path: two hard-linked paths to the same file have similar status, and none of them is more canonical than the other!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I never claimed the opposite. That said, I believe that a program should not output debugging messages with canonicalized paths anyway - not if one wants the user to understand *which* file is being mentioned without jumping through a lot of hoops...

Answer (score 1):

Well I can see this question is about 1 year old. But right now I was looking for a way of doing this. And I found it. For getting the device node using the file descritor you can combine `stat` and `libudev` here is an example:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libudev.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct stat sb;

    // Get a file descriptor to the file.
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);

    // Get stats for that file descriptor.
    if (fstat(fd, &sb) == -1) {
        perror("stat");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Create the udev context.
    struct udev *udev;
    udev = udev_new();

    // Create de udev_device from the dev_t obtained from stat.
    struct udev_device *dev;
    dev = udev_device_new_from_devnum(udev, 'b', sb.st_dev);

    // Finally obtain the node.
    const char* node  = udev_device_get_devnode(dev);

    udev_unref(udev);

    std::cout << "The file is in:    " << node << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the [fstat(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fstat.2.html) syscall, perhaps also [fstatfs(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fstatfs.2.html). Check that it succeeded.

```
  struct stat st;
  memset (&st, 0, sizeof(st));
  if (fstat (fd, &st))
    perror("fstat");
  else {
    // use st, notably st.st_rdev
  }
```

Remember that you could have a device outside of `/dev`. If you are sure that your device is in it, you could [stat(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/stat.2.html) every entry in it, and compare their `st_rdev`

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (it is online under a free license, but you may want to buy the book).

Comment: Thanks gonna try that one out.

Comment: fstat doesn't work i get a bad address. fstat(devlist[iter], buff);

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, just use `fstat` on an opened file descriptor. If it fails, check `errno` The `buf` second argument to `fstat` usually points to a local variable.

Comment: It's working but what i'm getting is number. is there a way for me to get the device node?.. eg. /dev/ttyUSB0?.

Comment: Read some books about Linux and Unix programming (to understand that a file might have several file paths). So there might not be any canonical file path. You could scan all the `/dev/` tree and use `fstat` or `stat` on each device file inside. Don't call `/dev/ttyUSB0` a device node, it is just a file path.

Comment: Okay thanks... I need something like this udev_device_get_devnode(dev)

Comment: It does not exist. You can do a hard `link(2)`, e.g. with `ln /dev/ttyUSB0 /tmp/myUsbZero` (or perhaps `/dev/MyUsbZero`) and then both `/dev/ttyUSB0` and `/tmp/myUsbZero` are file paths for the same device file. You are misunderstanding the notion of file paths.